# Regression coefficients by group in R?

Tags: r, regression, regression-coefficients

I have a dataframe with a group variable GRP (ranging from 1-100) and an X and Y for each one. I'd like to get a list of the regression intercepts and slopes for lm(Y~X) within each group. The intercepts and slopes don't need to be in the same dataframe.

Any suggestions? R beginner here, so simplicity would be great!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

data.table also has great tools for solving problems such as this:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.table(x=runif(100), y=runif(100), grp=rep(1:2,50))
dat[,coef(lm(y~x)),by=grp]
```

The first row in each group is the intercept, and the second row is the coefficient:

```
     grp         V1
[1,]   1  0.5991761
[2,]   1 -0.1350489
[3,]   2  0.4401174
[4,]   2  0.1400153
```

If you'de rather have a wide data.frame, that just takes a little more specification:

```
dat[,list(intercept=coef(lm(y~x))[1], coef=coef(lm(y~x))[2]),by=grp]
     grp intercept       coef
[1,]   1 0.5991761 -0.1350489
[2,]   2 0.4401174  0.1400153
```

Or you could put it even more succinctly as:

```
    dat[,as.list(coef(lm(y~x))),by=grp]
    (Intercept)          x
    1:   1   0.5991761 -0.1350489
    2:   2   0.4401174  0.1400153
```

Comment: Thanks very much! This worked great. Just wondering: in the wide format code, what is the purpose of the first comma (right before "list")?

Comment: @Lyra that's how you tell data.table what function you want it to use to operate on the columns.

Answer (score 12):

The responses by @Henry and @Zach both work, but I think the most straight-forward way to do what you want is to use `lmList` in the `nlme` package:

```
dat <- data.frame(
  GRP = sample(c("A","B","C"), 100, replace=TRUE), 
  X = runif(100), 
  Y = runif(100)
)
require(nlme)
lmList(Y ~ X | GRP, data=dat)
```

Comment: That is cool - I had no idea that existed.

Comment: smiling, I'm working with data with many companies and their financial data. Like Lyra, I'd like to regress select columns against each other within each company and report the coefficients for each company. I tried using your lmList method, but instead of getting unique coefficients for each company, I get the coefficients as if I regressed all the data. Do you know why this is?

Comment: @user2303635 It's difficult to say why that's happening without knowing more. I suggest you ask a new question providing the details of your issue (maybe on [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r)?). The answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169539) might also help you.

Answer (score 7):

Adapting from `help("by")`, this example may meet your needs

```
mydf <- data.frame( GRP = rep(c("A","B","C"), each=100), X = rep(1:100,3), 
                    Y = rep(c(2,4,8),each=100) + 
                        rep(c(4,2,1),each=100) * rep(1:100,3) + rnorm(300))   
by(mydf, mydf$GRP, function(z) lm(Y ~ X, data = z))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use package "tidyr" you could do the following

```
library(data.table)
library(tidyr)
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.table(x=runif(100), y=runif(100), grp=rep(1:2,50))

ncoefs <- 1
dat <- dat[, coef( lm(y ~ x) ), by = grp]
dat[, est := rep( c("intercept", "coef"), .N/(ncoefs + 1)) ]
dat <- dat %>% spread(est, V1)
```

The result is

```
   grp       coef intercept
1:   1 -0.1350489 0.5991761
2:   2  0.1400153 0.4401174
```

This method is easy to scale up and must be faster than estimating the regression for each coefficient.